# Узнать размер файла из входящего потока

Tags: golang

Задача:
Стягивать файл по ссылке, проверять его размер и передавать содержимое ответа дальше.

Код:

```
respGetFile, err := http.Get(urlFile)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer respGetFile.Body.Close()
```

**Вопрос:**
Какой наименее ресурсозатратный метод, для получения размера файла, полученного из потока?  На текущий момент приходит в голову только сохранять это как временный файл, получать его размер и после стирать.

Comment: У ответа есть поле `ContentLength` https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В протоколе HTTP есть специальный запрос HEAD - это как GET, только возвращает ответ без тела. Но со всеми заголовками.

Вам достаточно сделать запрос HEAD и посмотреть заголовок `Content-Length` в ответе.

Вот пример программы, которая пользуется запросом HEAD и заголовком `Content-Length` для определения размера файла. Для примера выбран дистрибутив Ububtu, который точно не захочется качать для определения размера )

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    var clt = &http.Client{}
    urlFile := "http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/18.04.4/ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso"

    rsp, err := clt.Head(urlFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("HEAD request failed", err)
        return
    } else {
        // по-хорошему, тут надо обработать статус запроса
        fmt.Println("File size", rsp.ContentLength)
    }
}
```

Результат работы программы: 2126544896

Я не скачивал для проверки, но вполне соответствует заявленным 2 гигабайтам.

Сразу скажу, что (а) не все сервера поддерживают заголовок HEAD, и (б) не все сервера отдают заголовок Content-Length при скачивании файла. Поэтому в общем случае этот метод не гарантирует правильный ответ. Конечно, вариант со скачиванием безопасней.